# JQuery attr() is not function, how to turn it in an object?

Tags: jquery

I have an error with `attr()` in jQuery - it is not a function. I understand the problem, my element is not in the DOM and I should turn it into an object. However I don't see how to do it.

```
<div class="progress progress_height shadow">
  <div id="progress_bar" class="progress-bar bg-info pg-width" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

```js
// Works
$("#progress_bar").text(iTempsMax); 

// Doesn't works
$("#progress_bar").attr("aria-valuenow").val(iTempsMax);
```

How could I turn into object for the last JS line?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the problem, my element is not in the DOM and I should turn it into an object

This is not the problem.

The issue is because `attr()` returns a string, not a jQuery object, so you can't chain `val()` off it. You need to separate the calls to the same jQuery object.

```
let $el = $("#progress_bar");
let valuenow = $el.attr("aria-valuenow");
$el.val(iTempsMax); // set the value
```

Alternatively, set the `val()` first, then get the attribute, although this is potentially obfuscates the `val()` call.

```
let valuenow = $("#progress_bar").val(iTempsMax).attr("aria-valuenow");
```

Using this pattern is a matter of personal preference over code clarity or brevity:

On the other hand if you are attempting to *only* set the value of the `aria-valuenow` attribute (and not the `value` attribute of the element itself) then you need to omit the `val()` call and pass the second argument to `attr()`, like this:

```
$("#progress_bar").attr("aria-valuenow", iTempsMax);
```

Comment: @Wimanicesir `val()` and `attr(key, value)` are not the same thing

Comment: I know, look in comments of my solution. I just suppose he wants to change the value of his attribute and tried it this way.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to change the value of your attribute? The attr() function accepts a second argument to set this:

```
$("#progress_bar").attr("aria-valuenow", iTempsMax)
```

> https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: `aria-valuenow` is not the same attribute as `value`.

Comment: No, I mean he wants to set the value of that attribute to the given variable

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.